# Set font in h4() text and pickerInput in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

Is it possible to set the font for the `h4()` text `Filters` and the `pickerInput()` label and choices to Montserrat in shinydashboard?

```
library(extrafont)
font_import()
loadfonts(device = "win")



library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  
  h4("Filters"),
  tags$hr(),
  
  fluidRow(column(12,
                  pickerInput(
                    inputId = "iss",
                    label = "Issue", 
                    choices = colnames(mtcars),
                    multiple = F,
                    
                  )           
  ))
  
)

body <- dashboardBody(fluidPage(
  )
  
)


ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'Search', header, sidebar, body)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add custom fonts using the `tags$p` call.

```
h4(tags$p("Filters", style = "font-family: Montserrat;"))
label = tags$p("Issue", style = "font-family: Montserrat;")
```

Comment: thanks and what about the text in choices of pickerInput?